# How Can I Use Sort or another bash cmd To Get 1 line from all the lines if 1st 2nd and 3rd Field are The same

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, grep

I have a file named file.txt

```
$cat file.txt

1./abc/cde/go/ftg133333.jpg
2./abc/cde/go/ftg24555.jpg
3./abc/cde/go/ftg133333.gif
4./abt/cte/come/ftg24555.jpg
5./abc/cde/go/ftg133333.jpg
6./abc/cde/go/ftg24555.pdf
```

MY GOAL: To get only one line from lines who's first, second and third PATH are the same and have the same file EXTENSION.
Note each PATH is separated by forward slash "/". Eg in the first line of the list, the first PATH is abc, second PATH is cde and third PATH is go.
File EXTENSION is .jpg, .gif,.pdf... always at the end of the line.

HERE IS WHAT I TRIED

```
sort -u -t '/' -k1 -k2 -k3
```

My thoughts
Using / as a delimiter gives me 4 fields in each line. Sorting them with "-u" will remove all but 1 line with unique First, Second and 3rd field/PATH. But obviously, I didn't take into account the EXTENSION(jpg,pdf,gif) in this case.

MY QUESTION

1. I need a way to grep only 1 of the lines if the first, second and third field are same and have the same EXTENSION using "/" as delimiter to divide it into fields. I want to output it to a another file, say file2.txt.
2. In the file2.txt, how do I add a word say "KALI" before the extension in each line, so it will look something like /abc/cde/go/ftg13333KALI.jpg using line 1 as an example in file.txt above.

Desired Output

```
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.jpg 
/abt/cte/come/ftg24555KALI.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.gif
/abc/cde/go/ftg24555KALI.pdf
```

COMMENT

1. Line 1,2 & 5 have the same 1st,2nd and 3rd field, with same file extension
   ".jpg" so only line 1 should be in the output.
2. Line 3 is in the output even though it has same 1st,2nd and 3rd field with
   1,2 and 5, because the extension is different ".gif".
3. Line 4 has different 1st, 2nd and 3rd field, hence it in output.
4. Line 6 is in the output even though it has same 1st,2nd and 3rd field with
   1,2 and 5, because the extension is different ".pdf".

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{                                  # using awk
    n=split($0,a,/\//)                    # split by / to get all path components
    m=split(a[n],b,".")                   # split last by . to get the extension
}
m>1 && !seen[a[2],a[3],a[4],b[m]]++ {     # if ext exists and is unique with 3 1st dirs
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)                     # loop component parts and print
        printf "/%s%s",a[i],(i==n?ORS:"")
}' file
```

Output:

```
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333.gif
/abt/cte/come/ftg24555.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg24555.pdf
```

I `split` by `/` separately from `.`s in case there are `.`s in dir names.

Missed the `KALI` part:

```
$ awk '{
    n=split($0,a,/\//)
    m=split(a[n],b,".")
}
m>1&&!seen[a[2],a[3],a[4],b[m]]++ {
    for(i=2;i<n;i++)
        printf "/%s",a[i]
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        printf "%s%s",(i==1?"/":(i==m?"KALI.":".")),b[i]
    print ""
}' file
```

Output:

```
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.gif
/abt/cte/come/ftg24555KALI.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg24555KALI.pdf
```

Comment: This is great James, can you add the FUZZ part to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F/ '{ split($5, ext, "\\.")
             if (!(($2,$3,$4,ext[2]) in files)) files[$2,$3,$4,ext[2]]=$0
           }
           END { for (f in files) {
                   sub("\\.", "KALI.", files[f])
                   print files[f]
               }}' input.txt 
/abt/cte/come/ftg24555KALI.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.gif
/abc/cde/go/ftg24555KALI.pdf
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333KALI.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, in the case where each line do not have equal fields, how can this be done? eg. /abc/def/hth/go.gif  /abd/def/go.pdf   /adg/hhhuu/jyyfhh/uui/htdgd/ytehiu/ghte/dgto.jpg

Comment: @Trendingmike _how can this be done_ How should it handled, if the question is: _- - if 1st 2nd and 3rd Field are The same_ and there are more or less than 3 fields? Please update your question with such requirement and add related example cases to the sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'[./]' '!a[$2,$3,$4,$NF]++' file

/abc/cde/go/ftg133333.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg133333.gif
/abt/cte/come/ftg24555.jpg
/abc/cde/go/ftg24555.pdf
```

assumes `.` doesn't exist in directory names (not necessarily true in general).

Comment: This is Great and simple. Please can you answer the second question? How do I add the word FUZZ before the end of the extension, keeping in mind the each line may have different number of fields. The output should look something like /go/come/here/toFUZZ.pdf    /go/come/what/you/any/meFUZZ.jpg      /come/go/make/u/me/ghkFUZZ.gif